# Outputs for apply()

Tags: javascript

```
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => Math.max( acc.x, cur.x );

let maxCallback2 = ( max, cur ) => Math.max( max, cur );
[ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ].reduce( maxCallback );   // NaN
[ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }            ].reduce( maxCallback );   // 22
```

Can someone please explain to me how those two outputs work. Why is the first output a Nan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the wrong type of data type when using the callback `maxCallback`.  Return the max object as the same type as the elements in the array.

```js
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => ({ x: Math.max( acc.x, cur.x )});


console.log([ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ].reduce(maxCallback)); // {x: 42}

console.log([ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }].reduce(maxCallback)); // {x:22}

console.log([ { x: 211 }, { x: 21 },{ x: 22 },{ x: 23 }].reduce(maxCallback));  // {x:211}
```

Comment: I saw this above mentioned question in mdn site when i tried to look for apply(). So was the output for first console.log() due to not returning same data type as the elements of array or is it something else. How does it work?

Comment: For the first time acc is by default it is the initial element and starts from index 1. Ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

So for the check `Math.max( acc.x, cur.x )` the acc is `{x:2}` and the second value is  `{ x: 21 }`  and returns 22 as result. Since there are only 2 elements and the loop ends and doesn't fail

But when there are more element, the acc holds currently value `22`. Now ` Math.max( acc.x, cur.x )` becomes `Math.max( undefined,  42 )` , since `22.x` is undefined. Here 22 is the value returned by function.

Comment: `Math.max( undefined,  42 )` is NaN

Answer (score 2):

The reduce function should return an object with the same format as the ones in the array:

```
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => ({ x: Math.max( acc.x, cur.x )});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code for your goal

```
console.log([ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ].reduce((acc, cur) => {
 return (acc < cur.x) ? (acc = cur.x) : acc 
}, 0)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the two option of having both parameters of the callback

- as numerical values, or
- as objects,

you need to return the same type, either numbers or objects to ensure the same wanted type for the next loop of reduce.

By knowing the data structure in advance and by wanting a numerical value as result, a *`startValue`* as second paramter of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) comes in handy. This value has to have the same type as the result and it goes into the folding function as first parameter.

This approach prevents error on empty arrays as well

```
Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

and takes a really small value, like `-Infinity` as greatest negative value. If a symbolic value is not wanted, you could take `-Number.MAX_VALUE` instead.

```js
let max = (m, { x }) => Math.max(m, x);

console.log([{ x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 }].reduce(max, -Infinity)); // 42
console.log([{ x: 2 }, { x: 22 }           ].reduce(max, -Infinity)); // 22
console.log([                              ].reduce(max, -Infinity)); // -Infinity
console.log([                              ].reduce(max));            // Error
```